# Environment Variable for PYTHONPATH

Tags: command-line, bash, python, environment-variables

I have joined my first open source project, and with these projects, obviously come packages containing modules.

Before I delve in, this is the file structure of the project:

```
-Opensource-Project
    -README.md
    -main.py
    -modules
        -__init__.py
        -src
            -lyrics.py
        -tests
            -test_lyrics.py
```

Now inside of test_lyrics.py:

```
import modules

def test_lyrics():
    assert('lyrics' == modules.process_query('paradise lyrics')[0])
```

When I run this file, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named modules
```

I have done research, and have found many past questions suggesting this:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/Opensource-Project/modules"
```

Now, I do this, because this is where the highest level **init**.py is, in the modules directory.

On top of that when I run:

```
>>import os
>>os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
```

It returns

```
>>:/home/Opensource-Project/modules
```

And yes, it just remains the variable for the session; once I close the terminal, it is gone.

Lastly, I check .bashrc and .profile, and it is not included in there.

What can I do to permanently add this path for the project and have python recognize these packages? Keep in mind, I am new to professional software development.

Thanks

Comment: See [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables).